# Select data that is ordered from sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to to get data with it ordered by a column but it is not working. Any idea on why?

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getMonthData(String month,String year, String name){
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> activityArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM activity WHERE year='"+year+"' AND month='"+month+"' AND name=? ORDER BY day ASC";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery,new String[] { name });
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            HashMap<String, String> activityMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            activityMap.put("day",cursor.getString(2).toString());

            activityArrayList.add(activityMap);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return  activityArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I stored day as TEXT so it was order lexicographical. So I have to cast it to REAL. Using "CAST(day AS REAL)".